# Need to pass string argument with single quotes using argparse

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments

I have a requirement where I have to pass arguments to python script in the exact order below. **I cannot change how the script gets called.**

```
py_script.py -W ' code=123 and fruits='Apple' '
```

`-W` argument is `string` within single quotes. The string inturn contains a single quotes(fruits=`'Apple'`)

I am using `argparse` to deal with this

Code:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="abc")
parser.add_argument('-W', '--filt', metavar='', help="Filter Condition", nargs='+')

args = parser.parse_args()
arg_str = ' '.join(args.filt)
print(args.arg_str)
```

Expected result:

```
code=123 and fruits='Apple'
```

Actual result:

```
code=123 and fruits=Apple
```

The code is stripping off the single quotes. How do i get the expected result?

Comment: What is `input_argument`? Please don't post code with undefined variable names.

Comment: -W ' code=123 and fruits='Apple' '

Comment: No, it is not. With your code I get `NameError: name 'input_argument' is not defined`.

Comment: what is the code of `input_arguement`?

Comment: Sorry. Fxed the code. please try now

Comment: I get a list of strings: `["'", 'code=123', 'and', "fruits='Apple'", "'"]` not a string `code=123 and fruits=Apple`

Comment: modified. try now

Answer (score 2):

### Use double quotes

One solution is to use double quotes around the argument, like this:

```py
python script.py -W " code=123 and fruits='Apple' "
```

It is not the argparser package that is stripping off the single quotes. It is Python's built-in sys.argv handling of the arguments, and/or the Python processor itself.

Python require escapes to handle the same type of quote (single or double), but you can nest raw quotes of the opposite type without an escape character. If this violates the rules for the requirement - then you likely need to use a different language or push-back on the requirements.

---

### Analysis

You can test this by directly viewing the sys.argv output.

**sysargtest.py:**

```py
import sys

for arg in sys.argv:
   print('"{}"'.format(arg))
```

If I feed in `python sysargtest.py -W ' code=123 and fruits='Apple' '`

the result is:

```bsh
$ py sysargtest.py -W ' code=123 and fruits='Apple' '
"sysargtest.py"
"-W"
" code=123 and fruits=Apple "
```

with the single quotes stripped.  One way to solve this is using double quotes instead of single on the command line, if that is not part of your requirement:

```bsh
$ py sysargtest.py -W " code=123 and fruits='Apple' "
"sysargtest.py"
"-W"
" code=123 and fruits='Apple' "
```

With that change argparse will work on the original script:

```bsh
$ py script.py -W " code=123 and fruits='Apple' "
[" code=123 and fruits='Apple' "]
```

Comment: Note: the question keeps changing... so might be out of date.  :)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But this python file is called using a shell script. I don't have any control over the shell script. The shell script uses double quotes as arguments within which the python file is called. So I am not able to use double quotes as argument. PFB the shell script call, shell_script.ksh -p py_script.py -a "-W ' code=123 and fruits='Apple' ' "

Comment: Right, that's what I understood from the original post. I believe you cannot use Python without a change to the script - my point about changing the requirement is that as a programmer, you always have the opportunity to provide feedback on the technical difficulty of a requirement, and those feeding down the requirements may accept your feedback and change the script. This is especially true if you provide a fix with the feedback (i.e. exactly how to change the script). I think your only other option is to not use Python. (P.S. just have them escape double quotes in the script).

Comment: Also note that if you change the script, then any input with double quotes would have the same problem. This is a language problem in how languages define and interpret strings and escape characters like quotes - it's not something you can work around directly - the interface between scripts has to accommodate language constraints - there is no way around that.

Comment: Thank you  :) Appreciate your time and advice!